# Send a response from the serve-side to client-side (Node.js, javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, single-page-application

Based on the following structure below, I want to send my response (simple array ["Tom", "Bob", "Sam"])  from the server.js to index.js  Is it possible?

**server.js**

```
app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "index.html"));
});

app.post('/settings', function(req, res, next){
res.status(200).json({
                ok: true,
                data: ["Tom", "Bob", "Sam"]
            }); 
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

**frontend/index.html**

```
    <nav class="nav">
        <a href="/">Dashboard</a>
        <a href="/settings">Settings</a>
    </nav>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/static/js/index.js"></script>
```

**/frontend/static/js/index.js**

```
document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml(); // load page.html
//console.log(data);
```

**/frontend/static/html/page.html**

```
        <button id="btn">Save</button>
       <script>
     
   var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  fetch('/settings', {
    method: 'POST', 
           headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        },
    body: JSON.stringify(anotherData), 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('got data: ', response.data);
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
  

}, false);
   </script>
```

Comment: Have you used `fetch()` before? It's part of your tags, so show us what you tried

Comment: You might also be interested in [`res.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.json)

Comment: What's the problem you're running into? You're already making a request to the /settings API of your node server and sending back an object with { ok, data}. Your response object should have a .data property containing your array. What do you expect/want to happen here?

Comment: @Evert I've updated my post (added that html with my initial POST request).  I can get my simple array there but still don't know how to access my result data in the index.js file. Is it possible?

Comment: @Joseph I can get my simple array inide my html but still don't know how to send my result data in the index.js file. Is it possible?

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. The easiest (and likely worst) alternative is to declare a variable above your fetch. i.e. - var result = null. Then, in your .then handler for your request, you can set result = response.data. Because you declared result in the script tag outside of your fetch call, result will be available from index.js. However, result will be null until the fetch completes. It would be better to move your fetch code into index.js and call any other functions you need once the fetch has completed - i.e. in the .then handler you defined.

Comment: Can you please show us your complete page.html code?

Comment: @Joseph oh you're right! I haven't even expected that it would work =)  Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! I went ahead and copied my comment into an answer so you can close the question out. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comment - I believe I understand what you're asking for now.

If you want to retrieve the data in your index.js file, the best way to handle this is probably to move your request code to index.js. Remove the  tag from your page.html file and instead put it in index.js. The code in index.js will run once the page loads, similarly to what is happening in the page script.

You'll need to wait until your fetch completes before doing anything with the resulting data, but if you move the fetch into your index.js you can call other functions in the file with the data, or alternatively declare a variable outside of your fetch call to let other functions in your index.js use it.